# Zero Knowledge Proof AND Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman, zero-knowledge-proofs

From my research, I think that everyone says that the result of a zero-knowledge proof (ZKP) is that the participants end up with a shared secret that can be used as a session key for a further symmetric encryption session between those two parties.  And then, all of the articles say that you follow this up by starting up something like a Diffie-Hellman (DH) session.

If I just got a secure key from the ZKP - why do I need DH?  Why don't I just expand the ZKP result and go from there?

Comment: Whatever those sources are, you shouldn't use them. ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my research, I think what everything says is that the result of a zero knowledge proof (ZKP) is that the participants end up with a shared secret
>   …
>   If I just got a secure key from the ZKP - why do I need DH? Why don't I just expand the ZKP result and go from there?

You obviously misunderstood ZKP at its core.

Zero knowledge proofs are [interactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system) or [non-interactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-interactive_zero-knowledge_proof) protocols or schemes for proving membership of a common input in a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) (or the analogous thing for [promise problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem)).

In the basic ZKP setting, there are only two parties, in which case something that *is unknown to one party* ​is simply *not a shared secret*. For proofs (or for [arguments](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/ZKsymmetric-eurocrypt.pdf)), the verifier is only necessarily convinced that a valid secret *exists*, **not** that the prover *has one*. Also see [proofs of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​
 ​